# Adding progress bar to webview

Tags: android, webview, progress-bar

I'm trying to open **WebView** on button click. I want to show the progress bar and set a default view in WebView. What changes should I make?
Also if web view can take progress bar's space?
Below is my code.

**xml file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.example.dell.ca1.Birthdays">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/archies"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                    android:text="Archies  >>"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fern"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                    android:text="FernsNPetals  >>"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/meeta"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                    android:text="Gifts By Meeta  >>"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pb"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/horizontalScrollView" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview_bday"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="525dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/horizontalScrollView" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Also if I can retain the data even after the back is pressed and start from beginning URL only when the app restarts.eg when I click "archies" button, view a product and then click "fernNpetals", then I click "archies" button, then I want to view the product page instead of the main page.

**java file**

```
    package com.example.dell.ca1;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;

    public class Birthdays extends AppCompatActivity {
        Button btn_fnp,btn_archies,btn_meeta;
        WebView webView;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_birthdays);
            webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview_bday);
            btn_archies=(Button)findViewById(R.id.archies);
            btn_fnp=(Button)findViewById(R.id.fern);
           // btn_igb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.igb);
            btn_meeta=(Button)findViewById(R.id.meeta);
            //progressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.pb);
            OnClickButton();
            webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        }
    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
    void OnClickButton()
    {
        btn_archies.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                webView.loadUrl("https://www.archiesonline.com/");
            }
        });
         btn_meeta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                 webView.loadUrl("https://www.giftsbymeeta.com/");
             }
         });

          btn_fnp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
                  webView.loadUrl("https://www.fnp.com/");
              }
          });
    }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Exactly I Can't Understand What Problem You faced any error or just progress not visible ?

Comment: Where should I make my progress bar visible and then where can I dismiss it

Comment: you can try this webview client http://www.technotalkative.com/android-load-webview-with-progressbar/

Answer (score 2):

> **You can use separate class for webViewClient**

For Example,

```
 private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        progressLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        progressLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progressLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

    }
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error){
        //Your code to do
        progressLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Internet Connection May not be active Or " + error , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

**Then call to webview,**

`myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());`

**Please modify as you like!!**

Happy java!!

Comment: overriding showProgress in shouldUrlOverride is key, i am looking for thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try like this...

```
 btn_archies.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                 wv1.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
                 wv1.loadUrl(url);
            }
        });


    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            progressDialog_webview = new ProgressDialog(Ppt_viewclass.this, R.style.MyTheme);
            progressDialog_webview.setMessage("Please wait ...");
            progressDialog_webview.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            if (progressDialog_webview != null) {
                progressDialog_webview.dismiss();
            }
        }
     }
```

I hope this will help you.....,All the best